# Use swagger JSON api definition with different hostname and schemes

Tags: json, rest, swagger

I want to use swagger with different hostnames but keep the same description file.  How is this possible,   For example, I tried an empty string for host and listed the schemes, but that did not work.

```
"host": "",
"schemes": [ "http" ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put markers like ${host} in your swagger definition file and process it with a template processor of your choice (perl script, Apache Velocity, Apache Freemarker, Maven resource processing, etc.).

An alternative approach that just came to my mind yet I have not tried myself involves using Postman extension for Google Chrome browser and its environmental variables. Postman can import swagger files into request collections and supports definition of environmental variables (see https://www.getpostman.com/docs/environments) for use in requests. Now, if you write the markers in the swagger definition file using the syntax notation of Postman and name those equal to your defined variables, you can keep requests and environment separated in Postman and you can change and reimport the swagger definitions anytime.

Answer (score 0):

swagger.js has to be modified to accept host option. swagger-UI passes options to swagger-js and it accepts a 'spec' parameter.The hosting page can load the swagger.json file by simply parsing it as JSON.parse.

Set 'host' in it and then pass it to swaggerUi constructor.

I would like you to go through the link once.

[Allow host to be specified](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/pull/510#issuecomment-121776076)

Hope it helps you in understanding.